# I cannot find the syntax errors described Can someone point out the error/s and provide explanation what I'm doing wrong?

Tags: mysql, sql, syntax, syntax-error

This is a past due homework question but have been stuck on it for 4 days studying for a quiz.  I cannot find the errors described and ready to pull my hair out.  Can someone provide explanation what I'm doing wrong?

**The error, as given:**

> ERROR 1064 (42000) at line 15: You have an error in your SQL syntax;
> check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the
> right syntax to use near '(Cat)ID
> ON DELETE CASCADE
> ,FOREIGN KEY(OwnerID) REFERENCES (Owner)' at line 6

I think how I'm referring to the CatID `FOREIGN KEY` is wrong, but nothing in my materials and internet searches have explained how.  And the error code indicates there should be quote usage for naming tables, which never existed in my lesson examples to follow.  This lesson is unique in that CatID is both a Primary and Foreign key.

Apologies ahead of time for the post length.  Just wanted to be thorough (as requested) and address potential questions BEFORE they are asked.

**The SQL Code**

NOTE: Lines 1-14 were given to me and hence, untouched.

```
CREATE TABLE Cat (
    ID              SMALLINT UNSIGNED AUTO_INCREMENT,
    RegisteredName  VARCHAR(15),
    PRIMARY KEY (ID)
);

CREATE TABLE Owner (
    ID             SMALLINT UNSIGNED AUTO_INCREMENT,
    FirstName      VARCHAR(20),
    LastName       VARCHAR(30),
    PRIMARY KEY (ID)
);

-- Your SQL statements go here 
CREATE TABLE LessonSchedule(
   CatID SMALLINT UNSIGNED NOT NULL
  ,OwnerID SMALLINT UNSIGNED 
  ,LessonDateTime DATETIME NOT NULL
  ,PRIMARY KEY (CatID, LessonDateTime)
  ,FOREIGN KEY(CatID) REFERENCES (Cat)ID
      ON DELETE CASCADE
  ,FOREIGN KEY(OwnerID) REFERENCES (Owner)ID
      ON DELETE SET NULL
);
```

**The Assignment Instructions:**

This is what I'm supposed to do.  Maybe I interpreted the instructions wrong?

> Create the Lessons table with columns:
>
> - CatID - integer with range 0 to 65 thousand, not NULL, partial primary key, foreign key references Cat(ID).
> - StudentID - integer with range 0 to 65 thousand, foreign key references Student(ID)
> - LessonDateTime - date/time, not NULL, partial primary key.
>
> If a row is deleted from Cat, the rows with the same cat ID should be deleted from Lessons automatically.
>
> If a row is deleted from Owner, the same owner IDs should be set to NULL in Lessons automatically.
>
> Note: Table and column names are case sensitive in the auto-grader.

**What I Tried and What Happened**

- Checked if comma placement and `);` placement is all good.  Seems to me it is?  Leading commas shouldn't make a difference and hear it's a good practice to get into for various reasons.  So, I tried it both ways (leading vs trailing commas).  Neither changed the error code given.
- Checked +70x for typos.  Found 3 instances, fixed.  Error code unchanged.
- Commenting out lines and sections to isolate issue.  Error code didn't really change except for which lines were being referred to...  this confused me more.
- I suspect the issue lies in how the `PRIMARY KEY` and `FOREIGN KEY` for CatID and Cat.ID, respectively, are written?
- The material says that the foreign key should be composite if the primary key is composite as well.  But, that is not congruent in my mind in this case?
- I.e. CatID in `PRIMARY KEY (CatID, LessonDateTime)` would simply be referenced using `FOREIGN KEY(CatID) REFERENCES (Cat)ID` not `FOREIGN KEY(CatID,LessonDateTime) REFERENCES (Cat)ID`?  It's only CatID that needs a reference.
- I tried putting Line 19 after Line 23 but that didn't change the error at all.
- I tried moving column order in LessonSchedule in case primary key columns had to be next to each other:

  1. CatID
  2. LessonDateTime
  3. OwnerID

Only other logical thing besides writing something wrong is using a keyword that isn't MySQL?

Comment: The obvious thing that isn't in your long list of things you've tried is checking the documentation for the version of MySQL that you're using, as suggested in the error message.

Comment: Thank you, Ken.  I simply pasted it and was wrapped in the "```" marks.  I'm guessing SO defaults to this behavior for convenience?  I'll remember to put error phrasing as a quote block next time!

Comment: Ken, this was done, I forgot to mention it.  Oddly, no versions are mentioned in my lectures at all.  I had to email the instructor on that.
edit:  MySQL 8 is the version.

Comment: Oh, I did mention the error code- The paragraph following The Error, As Given.   It mentioned nomenclature and single quote usage, which was also unsuccessful.

Everything is done inside an online learning module so I wonder if the auto-grader is a factor to consider?  Anyway, tons more was done not written.  I honestly have no more bandwidth after 50+hrs on this stupid question.  I've moved on since it was bogging me down and go back to it throughout the day multiple times.

Answer (score 2):

> Create the Lessons table with columns:
> CatID - integer with range 0 to 65 thousand, not NULL, partial primary key, foreign key references Cat(ID).

You have two typos -

> ,FOREIGN KEY(CatID) REFERENCES (Cat)ID
> ON DELETE CASCADE

Should be

```
  ,FOREIGN KEY(CatID) REFERENCES Cat(ID)
      ON DELETE CASCADE
```

And

> ,FOREIGN KEY(OwnerID) REFERENCES (Owner)ID
> ON DELETE SET NULL

Should be

```
  ,FOREIGN KEY(OwnerID) REFERENCES Owner(ID)
      ON DELETE SET NULL
```

The final result should be:

```sql
CREATE TABLE LessonSchedule(
   CatID SMALLINT UNSIGNED NOT NULL
  ,OwnerID SMALLINT UNSIGNED 
  ,LessonDateTime DATETIME NOT NULL
  ,PRIMARY KEY (CatID, LessonDateTime)
  ,FOREIGN KEY(CatID) REFERENCES Cat(ID)
      ON DELETE CASCADE
  ,FOREIGN KEY(OwnerID) REFERENCES Owner(ID)
      ON DELETE SET NULL
);
```

Comment: Thank you!  Damned typos, they will be the death of me, I swear.  That why I checked +70x...  That wasn't hyperbole or exaggeration.

I feel stupid but relieved, lol.  Apparently, Satisfied = Stupid * Relief
Thanks again!  The support is much appreciated.

Comment: @Xiong: FWIW, this information is in the documentation in the [Foreign Key Constraint Examples documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/create-table-foreign-keys.html), where they show examples. If you compare that example code to yours, the issue is pretty clear.

Comment: Yes, it is certainly clear now.  Comically so even.  I think blinders were put on at some point as I did look at many examples, both online and in my lesson materials.  It's incredible how simple errors are.  IDC how stupid I look, lol- I'm just happy to be over with it!

Anyway, this is a good lesson for a few things going forward.  Thanks again.  Truly, it's appreciated.

Edit:  I meant to say "... how incredibly stupid some errors are.  Mine for example!"